# scrapy_splash PNG bug

Tags: python, scrapy, python-3.6, scrapy-splash

Spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def start_requests(self):
        splash_args = {
            'png': 1,
            'render_all': 1,
            'wait': 2,
        }
        url = 'https://google.com'
        yield SplashRequest(
            url,
            callback=self.parse_splash,
            endpoint='render.png',
            args=splash_args
        )
        yield scrapy.Request(
            f"http://localhost:8050/render.png?url={url}&wait=2&render_all=1",
            self.parse_request,
        )

    def parse_request(self, response):
        with open('request.png', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

    def parse_splash(self, response):
        with open('splash.png', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Problem: with scrapy.Request all ok, but in splash.png I see this instead of the Google page screenshot. What's wrong with SplashRequest?

[image]

P.S. [Issue](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/138) added

Comment: I tested your code with Python 3.4.2, Scrapy 1.4.0, scrapy_splash 0.7.2 and it worked for me. Have you added all the infos in settings.py (as in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-splash/)?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. But then I noticed that it's not just a problem with how the image is being processed, but how scrapy is processing the splash response. Splash by itself is working fine (through browser and also through curl), but not with scrapy....

Comment: possible answer(not my and i'm not try it) added to issue